# Mount .sparseimage from .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, mount

I need to mount a .sparseimage from .bash_profile but I don't get how to do it. I tried:

```
alias of22='hdiutil attach "Documents/OF.sparseimage" -mountpoint "$HOME/OpenFOAM" > /dev/null ; . $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.0/etc/bashrc'
```

but this gives me:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable filesystem
```

if I double-click on it or I put it in Startup Items it works (but i need also to source the bashrc after the mount)

What's the problem?

Comment: Why > /dev/null - perhpas that output might give some info, also what is the error when you type just the hdiutil util in the e terminal and which directory are you in. ie break the command down into iys smaller pieces

Comment: What output do you see when using: `hdiutil imageinfo Documents/OF.sparseimage`?

Comment: @EddieKelley 
`Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: Is the disk image already attached? Try to unmount it, and then get image info...

Comment: @EddieKelley I'm sure it's not already mounted ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `open(1)` command can do it:

```
/usr/bin/open /full/path/to/OF.sparseimage
```

Comment: Why downvote a correct answer? Did I miss something?

Comment: As soon as I come back home I Try and I check.

Comment: Perfect. This works!! :D

Comment: This doesn't allow the user to specify the mount point.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the command you use will mount the disk image, but there are two problems I see.

Before I get into those I want to clarify to all readers (as I had this problem), the following command will mount a disk image:

```
hdiutil attach image_name.sparseimage -mountpoint mount_point
```

where you specify `image_name.sparseimage` and `mount_point` to your liking.

Here are the problems with your specific case that I see:

1) You are not mounting it in the bash_profile.  You are creating an alias.  You must run the alias first to mount the disk image (with `of22` in your case).

2) Seems like you've done #1 because you get the error message "no mountable filesystem".  This is probably because the disk image is using a relative path, which means you must run `of22` from the parent directory (which seems to be your home directory in this case).

Try changing the command to

```
hdiutil attach "$HOME/Documents/OF.sparseimage" -mountpoint "$HOME/OpenFOAM"
```

Notice the addition of "$HOME".